# Lazy load Js not working in Magento2.2.0/1/2 Version

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, jquery, magento2.2.2, lazyload

I have https://www.magebees.com/lazy-load-images-extension-for-magento-2.html

this one extension, but not working properly- **js errors like window undefined**..

[image]

Comment: According to the changelog the extension was last updated at 2016-12-23. Which means that it's likely not compatible with Magento 2.2.x. I suggest you contact the extension developers for this issue.

Comment: no it's also not working in 2.2.0 and 2.2.1.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/magepal/magento2-catalog-lazy-load